# Extjs JSON response

Tags: php, ajax, json, extjs, response

I have a form, which sends data to the server. I process the form with a PHP script, which can return 3 differents JSON strings:

**One**

```
exit("{\"success\":\"false\", \"msg\":\"Las claves no cohinciden\"}");
```

**Two**

```
exit("{\"success\":\"false\", \"msg\":\"".$failure->getMessage()."\"}");
```

**Three**

```
exit("{\"success\":\"true\",\"msg\":\"El usuario: $nombreUsuario ha sido dado de alta correctamente.\"}");
```

The first and second strings, are errors to show. The third string is the normal case.
When the script return some of these values, i catch the response with ExtJs do:

```
var respuesta = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
```

But, when do:

```
console.log(respuesta);
```

Firebug console says that "respuesta" are undefinied.
Any idea ?

Comment: Try using break point in firebug to see what you get in response or use alert(response.responseText). I guess, you response does not have responseText in it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are outputting JSON for using in AJAX, it's best to set the headers for JSON and return properly formatted JSON. In my below example, we create a normal PHP array with your response and convert it to JSON with `json_encode()`.

Try it. I've had issues before with Javascript not taking a string in as JSON before without a proper content type and formatting.

```
<?php

$response = array("success" => "false", "msg" => "Las claves no cohinciden");

header("Content-type: application/json");
exit(json_encode($response));

?>
```

Optionally, if you have jQuery... You can do `$.parseJSON('your string');` to output JSON from a string.

Comment: Ok.Thanks!, but not work :'(. I modified the PHP script:
In the first line added:

`header("Content-type: application/json");`
Then, lines that generate the json string:
`$response = array("success" => "false","msg" => "Las claves ingresadas no cohinciden.");`
`exit(json_encode($response));`
The ExtJs code was not changed:
`var respuesta = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
 console.log(response.responseText);
 if(respuesta.success == true){ ... }`
The errors persists, and are equals.

Comment: Sory but the bad lines break format. I dont know the correct way to write.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this url for testing your Json code:

http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.UNr9FhhQ-gY